# How should i understand built-in function bin(x)?

Tags: python

> [**`bin(x)`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bin)
>
> Convert an integer number to a binary string. The result is a valid Python expression. If `x` is not a Python int object, it has to define an `__index__()` method that returns an integer.

So if i want to get `bin` from `Cadilac` what should i do with this string and `__index__()` method? How to syntaticly proper compose them?

Comment: What's your desired output for the string `Cadillac`? The `bin()` function is for converting numbers into a string of 0s and 1s for text output.

Comment: Can i somehow convert string to a binary string by this method? Now I think i can't. Is there method to get binary string of string?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "binary string". Is it a string with the binary representation of every character of the input? Assuming there was a function called `binstring()` that does what you want, what would be the value of `binstring('Cadilac')`?

Comment: i don't know. i don't know from where can i import `binstring()`. Could You tell me?

Comment: You want a binary representation of the string 'Cadillac' ?

Comment: @Cadilac `binstring()` doesn't exist. If it existed, what, *exactly*, would it do? Provide an example.

Comment: I don't know. I thinking that maybe somewhere it is important because for some reason there is function like `bin(x)`. Don't beat me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
>>> for c in "Cadillac":
...     n = ord(c)                  # convert the character to a number
...     print '{0:08b}'.format(n)   # show the number with 8 binary digits
... 
01000011
01100001
01100100
01101001
01101100
01101100
01100001
01100011
```

Comment: And your answer is much cleaner and clearer than mine. Thanks! I still have much to learn about 'format'.

Answer (score 1):

```
car = "Cadillac"
binstr = "".join( [ bin((1<<8)+ord(s))[3:] for s in car ] )
```

binstr =
'10000111100001110010011010011101100110110011000011100011'

Loop over the chars in the string. ord() converts char to its ordinal (ASCII). bin() converts to a binary string. [2:] skips the '0b'. "".join() combines all together into a single string.

EDIT. bin() truncates leading zeroes, as pointed out by a commentator. Based on the context of the original question, (character strings), I'm assuming we're always using 8-bit characters, my change prepends a high bit at position 8 which is stripped by the [3:]. I cheat. Which will, of course, fail on Unicode strings.

```
bin(1<<8+0)[3:]
```

'00000000'

```
len(bin(1<<8+0)[3:])
```

8

```
"".join( [ bin((1<<8)+ord(s))[3:] for s in "Cadillac" ] )
```

'0100001101100001011001000110100101101100011011000110000101100011'

Comment: This example just leads to a jumble of bits because bin() trims leading zeros.  Some of the characters will be added as 6 bits and some as 7 bits and there is no separator to distinguish where a character starts and stops.

Comment: Oops. You are quite correct. Fixing.

Comment: The API for bin(), oct(), and hex() is really irritating in this regard :-)